# android aapt on centos6.5 error segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: android, aapt

all

i try to run aapt on centos 6.5 ,but i got the error:

```
./aapt
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

i have installed them:

```
sudo yum install glibc.i686
sudo yum install zlib.i686
sudo yum install libstdc++.i686
```

and

```
ldd aapt
statically linked
```

and the error from /var/log/message:

```
aapt[30893]: segfault at 4 ip 0000000000e50552 sp 00000000ffcc0ccc error 4 in ld-2.12.so[e45000+1e000]
```

why it can't be run?

please help me...